# Why are my Sprite Nodes not resizing on my universal app?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

My sprite nodes sizes are incorrect after I changed the scale mode. I use @3x,@2x, and @1x images so SpriteKit usually automatically resizes them for me. They aren't resizing when I switch devices. For instance, on my iPhone 6s+, the sprite node sizes are perfect, while on my iPhone 5, the node sizes are the same size as they are on my iPhone 6s+. I've tried changing the scale mode to `.aspectFill` and `.resizeFill` but nothing works. Here is my GameViewController viewDidLoad currently:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = MainMenu(fileNamed:"MainMenu") {
    let skView = self.view as! SKView

      skView.showsPhysics = true
      skView.showsFPS = true
      skView.showsNodeCount = true
      skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

      scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
      scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y:0)

      scene.size = skView.bounds.size
      skView.presentScene(scene)
    } }
```

I don't know what's wrong. Also, here is a picture of how the nodes look on my iPhone 6s+: 
[image: iPhone 6s+]

And here is a picture of how the sprite nodes look on my iPhone 5:[image: iPhone 5]

I just don't know what's wrong. Nothing resizes.

Here is what happens if i remove scene.size = skView.bounds.size:
[image]

Comment: remove 
    `scene.size = skView.bounds.size`

Comment: looks right to me,  now you need to fix the positions of your nodes

Comment: @Knight0fDragon The node sizes are way smaller than when I first started the project (when they resized)

Comment: ..... ok looks like we have a bigger issue here, show me a picture of what MainMenu.sks looks like, take a picture of the xcode editor

Comment: Is this what you wanted?https://www.dropbox.com/s/41amxzstvyws8xd/Screenshot%202017-07-07%2016.31.35.png?dl=0 @Knight0fDragon

Comment: OK I see your problem, I am guessing you did not change the size of your scene.  It is probably 750x1334.  I would recommend changing this to 364x640 (This is iphone 6+ resolution at 1x) This will allow you to design for the 6+ and everything else will scale down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148644/discussion-between-josh-schlabach-and-knight0fdragon).

Answer (score 1):

Are the image sizes that same for all 3 images? If the 1x image is 64x64 the 2x should be 128x128 and the 3x should be 192x192.

Comment: No they are not the same size. They are like what you said they should be.